# HandbrakeCLI auto conversion

Tags: handbrake

I need to have this script read for files in C:/unc but then output the converted file in C:/enc

```
for /R C:\unc %%F in (*.mkv) do (
"C:\Program Files\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" --preset-import-file anime.json -Z "anime" --optimize --align-av -i "%%~fF" -o "%%~dpF%%~nF_conv.mp4"
if exist "%%~dpF%%~nF_conv.mp4" (
    "C:\Conversion\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%~fF" -i "%%~dpF%%~nF_conv.mp4" -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy "%%~dpF%%~nF.mp4"
    del "%%~fF"
    del "%%~dpF%%~nF_conv.mp4"
)
```

)